# record updated? when $stmt->execute() $stmt->affected_rows

Tags: php, prepared-statement

considering the following for my question:

```
$success = false;
$err_msg = '';
$sql = 'UPDATE task SET title = ? WHERE task_id = ?';

$conn = connect('w'); // create database connection: r= read, w= write

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init(); // initialize a prepared statement
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('si', $_POST['title'], $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

If i want to check if an insert or a deletion was succesfull, i could easily check for the affected_rows, like this:

```
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
   $success = true;
} else {
   $err_msg = $stmt->error;
}
```

If $stmt->affected_rows equals -1, it means that $stmt->execute() executed correctly but did not insert the record or did not delete the record successfully.

But, what about an update ? What is the correct way to deal with an update?

The way i do it is by checking for the return value :

```
$isRecordUpdated = $stmt->execute();

if (!$isRecordUpdated) {
   // execute failed, therefore NO record updated!
} else {
   //execute success, record updated!
}
```

Is that the correct way you guys are doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are really two equivalent and correct ways of doing this: either by checking the return value of `execute` as you do, or by checking the `affected_rows` value. -1 means the query errored out; 0 means that it did not affect (delete or update) any rows because there were none matching the query.

Since it seems there is no "better" way, you should pick what would be most convenient for your code. If e.g. using one approach over the other means that you can then share code among all types of queries, you might want to pick that one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the value from `mysql-affected-rows` into a property of that object when you call `execute()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php